# Need help extruding simple mesh

Tags: extrude

I'm working with a Minecraft animation, and am trying to get the hair of the character to extrude. I tried lining up cubes with the hair textured on the character and bumping them out, but there are always some overlaps leading to a weird grid look in the hair. How should I go about this extrusion?
[image]

Comment: Extrude in edit mode with e?

Comment: Also use snapping to vertices, activate it in the 3D view header and use by pressing `Ctrl`